# How to integrate Cobertura into Teamcity 6.5 build and get code coverage history?

Tags: java, teamcity, cobertura, teamcity-6

I would like to integrate Cobertura into my Teamcity build.  I'm using this link as a starting point:

http://jroller.com/ulc/entry/teamcity_2_custom_report_integration

But as far as I can tell that will only give me a current snapshot of the coverage.  Any ideas for getting historical charts/records for code coverage in Teamcity?

Is there a better method than the above link describes for integrating with Cobertura?

Comment: if it will not work with teamcity you can try [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) this has a timeline feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct integration with Cobertura for TeamCity AFAIK.

For getting TeamCity statistics charts and 7.0-to-be-introduced ability to fail a build on metric change, build script will need to report corresponding coverage-related [statistics values](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Custom+Chart#CustomChart-predefinedStatisticsKeys) via [service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatistics).

BTW, you might consider using IntelliJ IDEA [Code Coverage](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Code+Coverage) with TeamCity instead of a bit stagnated Cobertura.

Answer (score 3):

Going to accept Yaegor's answer as it most directly answers my question -- integrating Cobertura with TeamCity.  But a better overall solution, in our situation, was just to integrate teamcity with a [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) server.  [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) provides code coverage (with Cobertura or many other coverage tools), static analysis, and many other metrics out of the box with very little standup effort.